# "Do" or "Does" schools for the blind in Delhi equip enough assistive products for teaching?

Tags: questions

"Do" or "Does" schools for the blind in Delhi equip enough assistive products for teaching?

Which one is correct to use either "do" or "does" in the above sentence

Comment: What do you know about the difference between do and does - which one is used in singular and which one in plural?

Comment: Do for plural and does for singular ? using do is okay here since I'm talking about so many schools.     ((Does your school have assistive products ? or does your  school has assistive products? which one is correct first one...))

Comment: Do goes with schools (in plural) and does with a school (singular).